# Writing a Word Macro to Compare Values in Two Separate Documents

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am attempting to write a macro that will automatically verify that the forms present in two documents are the same.

To do this I need to search through one document and create an array that is a list of all of the forms in that document. Each form is designated by a unique code like AB001 or E363. I am currently searching for these terms and highlighting them using this code I blatantly stole off the internet.

```
    Dim word As Range
    Dim wordcollection(9) As String
    Dim words As Variant

    'Define list.
    'If you add or delete, change value above in Dim statement.
    wordcollection(0) = "PJ"
    wordcollection(1) = "E1233"
    wordcollection(2) = "E048"
    wordcollection(3) = "E144"
    wordcollection(4) = "E849"
    wordcollection(5) = "E977"
    wordcollection(6) = "IL0021"
    wordcollection(7) = "MISC001"
    wordcollection(8) = "CG0001"
    wordcollection(9) = "CG2107"


    'Set highlight color.
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow

    'Clear existing formatting and settings in Find feature.
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    'Set highlight to replace setting.
    Selection.Find.Replacement.Highlight = True

    'Cycle through document and find words in collection.
    'Highlight words when found.
    For Each word In ActiveDocument.words
        For Each words In wordcollection
            With Selection.Find
                .Text = words
                .Replacement.Text = ""
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                .Format = True
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
            End With
            Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

I need to figure out how to copy the values that **are** present in the document into a new array

Then I need to search another document for the same values and copy the values that are present in **that** document into **another** new array

Finally I need to compare both of the new arrays and print a list of the values that are present in new array A but not new array b and vice versa.

Any help would be appreciated. The extent of my VBA experience is writing macros to automatically copy data in formfields to new formfields so even a basic understanding of how to do this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The term "Form" has a special meaning in Word. Are these things you are searching Form Fields? And when you say they have a unique code identifying them, do you mean they have a unique Title or Tag on each?

Comment: Basically they are forms on an insurance policy. Every insurance policy form has an alphanumeric code associated with it that is unique. I am just trying to write a macro that compares the forms in one policy to the forms in another policy without having to actually look through the word doc. Unfortunately they are not in formfields so all text has to be searched.

Comment: This code is located anywhere in the document? Or, just in the Header or Footer?

Comment: Anywhere in the document, but the documents are only about three pages long. I think I could crack it if I just knew how to copy the results of the Selection.Find into an Array. So if it searches for the word "Apple" and finds it in the document it copies the word "Apple" into a new Array that I can name whatever .

Comment: Basically I just need a way to say "if FIND = true for word X then place word X in ARRAY Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a ReplaceAll in your existing code doesn't give you any runtime feedback. You have to isolate the Found variable and then you can determine what to do. My recommendation is to separate the single macro into two parts with the second macro providing the feedback that the code was found so that you can then take action.

To provide you with an example of what I am attempting to describe, below is an example and the output are separate text files that show what codes exist in each document. Hopefully you can adapt this to meet your requirements.

```
Sub FindCodes()
Dim doc As word.Document
Dim i As Long, wrkFolder As String, fName As String
Dim oFile As String, FileNum As Integer
Dim Codes(0 To 2) As String

Codes(0) = "PJ"
Codes(1) = "E1233"
Codes(2) = "E048"

On Error GoTo errHandler
wrkFolder = "c:\users\<your id>\documents\test\"
fName = Dir(wrkFolder & "*.docx", vbNormal)
Do While fName <> vbNullString
    Set doc = Documents.Open(wrkFolder & fName)
    oFile = Left(doc.FullName, InStrRev(doc.FullName, ".") - 1) & "_Codes.txt"
    On Error Resume Next
    Kill oFile
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    FileNum = FreeFile()
    Open oFile For Append As #FileNum
    Print #FileNum, doc.Name
    For i = 0 To UBound(Codes)
        If Not CheckDocument(doc, Codes(i)) = vbNullString Then
            'the code was found in the document
            'print it in a text file
            Print #FileNum, Codes(i)
        End If
    Next
    Close #FileNum
    doc.Save
    doc.Close
    fName = Dir()
Loop
errHandler:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Find Codes"
    Err.Clear
End If
End Sub

Private Function CheckDocument(ByRef doc As word.Document, StrCode As String) As String
Dim rng As word.Range
For Each rng In doc.StoryRanges
    'will search headers, footers and the document body
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Format = True
        .Forward = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Text = StrCode
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Execute
        If .Found Then
            'this will highlight the first code found and then exit
            'does it really need to highlight all places the code
            'was found? If so, comment out this IF statement and
            'use the loop method instead
            rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
            CheckDocument = .Text
            Exit Function
        End If
'            Do While .Found
'                rng.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
'                CheckDocument = .Text
'            Loop
    End With
Next
End Function
```